# Underbound length of a ternary linear code

Tags: coding-theory

I have to prove the following theorem:

Let $C$ be a ternary linear $[n,2,d]$-code. Prove that $d+ d/3 \leq n$.

Now I don't really see what the best approach for this would be. I was thinking maybe the generator matrix, but I didn't really get anywhere when trying this. Any tips?

Comment: $d+ d/3 \leq n$ looks weird, as it would be simpler to write $ \frac43 d \leq n$ Are you sure you got it right?

Comment: Yes I'm sure...

Comment: Hint: consider the possible columns of $G$ and how many linear combinatios produce a zero in each position....

Comment: This is a special case of [the Griesmer bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griesmer_bound#The_bound_for_the_general_case). The 2-dimensional case can, indeed, be proven the way leonbloy indicated. But the general result isn't very difficult either.